# Add "Hyperlink" to words in VSC (Visual Studio Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Quick question:
Is it possible to add Hyperlinks to words in a .txt document opened in VSC?
I've been looking for an extension to do that for me, but with no luck so far.
When clicking the word with the Hyperlink, I'd like it to open a specified folder on my PC

How would I do that?
Thx

Comment: Just open the required folders one by one and then you can use `File` > `Open Recently`

Comment: if hyperlinks refs for url, just ctrl + click to follow link.

Comment: @rioV8 that wouldn't really help me in this scenario though :/

Comment: what do you mean with `open folder`, the same as `File` > `Open Folder...`

Comment: @rioV8 I mean as in, I'd like to press a word in my text document, that'll automatically open an Explorer window. So let's say I have a folder in my C drive that's called "Games" if I were to link the word "Games" in my text document, it would then open that said folder when I'm pressing the word "Games"

Comment: but what if that folder `Games` is on the `D:` drive, what do you mean with `press a word in a text document`

Comment: @rioV8 but it wouldn't be? I don't think you understand what I'm trying to achieve here :)
I want a word in my text document to act as a hyperlink

Comment: But what if your directory is on the D drive or on some network share drive